# Spring TypeDescriptor for user defined generic class

Tags: java, spring, generics, type-erasure

I'm using spring generic conversion service for constructing request and responses for making SOAP/REST API calls.

I have two converters which takes a generic java class as input and converts them to same response java class. Spring's type descriptor is used inherently to resolve the parameters type and the spring converter invokes the appropriate converter class.

But this does not work for user defined generic classes. The below is my syntax.

```
public class PairAConverter extends
    ConversionServiceAwareConverter<Pair<ClassA, Param>, Response> {

public class PairBConverter extends
    ConversionServiceAwareConverter<Pair<ClassB, Param>, Response> {
```

now, when I invoke the converter using the below syntax:

```
Pair<ClassA, Param> pairA = Pair.of(classAObject, param);

TypeDescriptor fromType = TypeDescriptor.forObject(pairA); 

Response finalResponse = (Response) conversionService.convert(pairA, fromType,
    TypeDescriptor.valueOf(Response.class));
```

The runtime invocation does not have any indication on the type of objects within the `Pair` class due to type erasure and invokes the wrong converter all the time. I see this available for the Collection classes but no capability for user defined generic classes.

Is there a way to get the complete class details of the generic class by the type descriptor?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `TypeDescriptor` does not support generics in custom objects, it supports generics in collections/maps.
What you can do is, invoking protected `org.springframework.core.convert.TypeDescriptor#TypeDescriptor(org.springframework.core.ResolvableType, java.lang.Class<?>, java.lang.annotation.Annotation[])` constructor using your generic types:

```
Constructor<TypeDescriptor> constructor = TypeDescriptor.class.getConstructor(ResolvableType.class, Class.class, Annotation[].class);
ResolvableType resolvableType = ResolvableType.forClassWithGenerics(Pair.class, ClassA.class, Param.class);
TypeDescriptor fromType = constructor.newInstance(resolvableType, Pair.class, null); //Assuming Pair doesn't have any annotations
```

Then you can use your approach:

```
Response finalResponse = (Response) conversionService.convert(pairA, fromType,
TypeDescriptor.valueOf(Response.class));
```